# Doing Pouch/Couch Style synching with SQL databases

Tags: sql, synchronization, pouchdb, merge-replication

We need a replication/push mechanism compatible with SQL which functions like pouch/couch.

Specifically, we need to store data in browser, or on a local device, duirng remote data acquisition.  At the time of acquisition, connection to end point SQL servers may not be available.

We then would like, once connection  is returned, to communicate to the SQL server, and update its data.

We are not aware of any tools/techniques and would like some guidance.